# How to print the first object from the LinkedList using Iterator?

Tags: java, eclipse, iterator

Trying to print out objects from my `LinkedList` using iterator, but the first object does not get printed out, so it starts from the second one:

```
Car car1 = new Car("Koenigsegg CCXR Trevita", "BASASS1");
Car car2 = new Car("Lamborghini Veneno", "B1T3M3");
Car car3 = new Car("W Motors Lykan Hypersport", "NUMERO1");

public void addToList() {

    availableCarList.add(car1);
    availableCarList.add(car2);
    availableCarList.add(car3);

    System.out.print("Original contents of list: ");

    IIterator itr = availableCarList.getIterator();

    while(itr.hasNext()) {
        Object element = itr.next();
        System.out.print(element + " ");
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

Result:

[image: result]

What do I do wrong?

hasNext() and next() implemented in the LinkedList class:

```
private class Iterator<T> implements IIterator<T>
{

    private LinearNode<T> temp;
    public Iterator()
    {
        temp = (LinearNode<T>) front;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() 
    {
        return (temp.getNext() != null);
    }

    @Override
    public T next() 
    {
        if (temp == null)
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }

        temp = temp.getNext();
        return temp.getElement();
    }   
}
```

Comment: You need to provide the definition of `IIterator`, and presumably your `LinkedList` class, since `java.util.LinkedList` doesn't return an `IIterator`.

Comment: Or maybe just replace it with `Iterator`

Comment: If you'd been using `java.util.LinkedList` (and the `iterator()` method and the `java.util.Iterator` that returns), [your loop would print out the first element](http://ideone.com/kw2VK5). There is a problem with your implementation of the list and/or iterator.

Comment: IIterator is an interface and I implement its methods (hasNext() and next()) in the LinkedList class.

Comment: Well, something is obviously wrong with your `hasNext()` or `next()` method, then, but you haven't shown us them, so it's impossible to say what, exactly.

Comment: Uploaded hasNext() and next() implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the code you have shown us suggests that `LinkedList` is actually *your own class* ... not the standard `LinkedList`.

It is a really bad idea to name your classes with the same (short) name as a standard library class.  It confuses readers ... and that would include yourself if you looked at your code in 3+ months time.

The actual problem is most likely that your implementation of the list iterator is incorrect.  And it looks to me like you are skipping the first element in the list.

Given what `temp` contains, I think that:

1. the `hasNext()` method should be testing `temp`, not `temp.getNext()`
2. the `next()` method should be returning `temp.getElement()`, not `temp.getNext().getElement()`

Comment: If I do like you suggested, I am continuosly getting the first object, whitout switching to the next one.

Comment: Then you have not understood my suggestion.  Based on the new symptoms, you are now not advancing the iterator properly.  Please note that my Answer did not say anything about how to advance the iterator.  (I was assuming that you would *think about what I said* rather than treating my Answer as a copy-and-paste solution.  It isn't ... )